# Applying Law of Demeter in a way that does not improve design

Tags: oop, coupling, law-of-demeter, cohesion

Suppose, we have the following `Boy` class that tries to arrange a date with a `Girl` by analyzing her schedule (example in Java):

```
public class Boy {

  public boolean tryArrangeDate(Girl girl, Date time) {
    boolean success = true;
    for (GirlRoutine routine : girl.getSchedule()) {
      if (routine.happensAt(time)) {
        success = false;
        break;
      }
    }
    return success;
  }

}
```

`Boy.tryArrangeDate()` method clearly violates Law of Demeter because of `routine.happensAt()` call. One of the ways to resolve this is to move schedule analysis directly to `Girl` and avoid having a dependency on `GirlRoutine`. That would probably be one the best decisions in this case. RFC for `Boy` class will be reduced.

But suppose we choose a different direction for resolving violations of Law of Demeter and change the code in this way:

```
public class Boy {

  public boolean tryArrangeDate(Girl girl, Date time) {
    return isFree(girl.getSchedule(), time);
  }

  private boolean isFree(List<GirlRoutine> schedule, Date time) {
    boolean free = true;
    for (GirlRoutine routine : schedule) {
      if (happensAt(routine, time)) {
        free = false;
        break;
      }
    }
    return free;
  }

  private boolean happensAt(GirlRoutine routine, Date time) {
    return routine.happensAt(time);
  }

}
```

There are two private methods added that just delegate calls down to the `Girl` and her schedule / routines.

Each method taken individually does not seem to violate Law of Demeter (for simplicity reasons let us treat retrieval of item from collection as a primitive no-method-call operation). But overall we have not reduced RFC for this class, did not improve the cohesion, and actually increased WMC. *Tell, don't ask* principle is not preserved. So, Law of Demeter is satisfied but design is still flaky.

Question:
**Is it true that (formally) second code snippet does not violate Law of Demeter?**

*NOTE: Purpose of the question is NOT to find alternative solutions, but to confirm / refute that the solution adheres to the Law of Demeter*

Comment: I don't see how hiding property accesses behind function calls on the same class `Boy` changes anything. You are taking things too literally. If (and that's a theoretic if) you wanted to improve this side of things you should move the `isFree` method into the `Girl` class so that `tryArrangeDate` becomes `return girl.isFree(date)` as you mention.

Comment: @Jon Introducing `isFree` in the `Girl` class is the normal way of handling things. That is clear to me and it is described in the question formulation. All I want is to check if second code snippet violates Law of Demeter or not, that is it!

Comment: Changed question slightly to make it a bit more clear.

Answer (score 0):

**Update**

Since you're just asking if the second still violates the Law of Demeter, then yes, I'd argue it does. No matter how you *refactor* `tryArrangeDate`, it doesn't change the fact that it's calling a method from `GirlRoutine`. When the Law of Demeter mentions "any method of an object", I take it that it refers to methods accessible to other objects, methods that are exposed to the "outside world". The private methods in your second code snippet are merely helper methods to `tryArrangeDate`.

**Originally**

The `Girl` class is the "expert" when it comes to its own `GirlRoutine`s. As much as possible, you must hide it from anyone else. Remember the principle of [tell, don't ask](http://pragprog.com/articles/tell-dont-ask).

Perhaps you can do:

```
Response response = girl.askOut(boy, date);
```

Don't read it like the Girl instance is asking out the Boy instance; the rule of thumb I follow (most of the time) is that the object from which you call the method is the direct object of the action that the method represents. In this case, the direct object of `askOut` is the Girl instance.

The `Response` class can have information about how it went, or it can be something simple like:

```
enum Response { ACCEPTED, REJECTED }
```

This way, a `Girl` instance has everything it needs to know to accept or reject the `Boy` instance's request.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. Second code snippet in the question violates [tell, don't ask][http://pragprog.com/articles/tell-dont-ask] principle. That's crystal clear. My question is whether that code snippet violated LoD or not

Comment: Ok, I've updated my answer. The reason why I mentioned tell, don't ask principle is they go hand in hand as pointed out by the link I've provided.